# Laravel 7.6 419 page expired on form submission

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit a form and it's just redirecting me to unspecified location (to folder/index.blade.php) without saving the form with 419 Page Expired. I tried other ways to redirect to somewhere I want, It's just not working. I already have a crud build for blogs which is working and I created another controller for saving contact form.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" action="{{action('LeadsController@store')}}">

        @csrf

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="requirement">Requirement</label>
            <input type="text" name="requirement" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="requirement">
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>

        </form>
```

Comment: Have you adding @csrf on your form ?

Comment: Yes. I added it.

Comment: Try this tools for more information => composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev

Comment: Please share your code 'blade view`

Comment: what is the version of Laravel

Comment: laravel 7.6  and XAMPP for Windows 7.2.28

Comment: Have you change SESSION_DRIVER ?

Comment: No. I just used PHP artisan to create model, controller and migration. Same as I did for Blogs Crud. Just using Create Index and Store function in form.

Comment: can you add the first line of your form ? <form action....

Comment: try to use route name in action route( '.... and middleware :)

Comment: Not working. Any thing else I can try.

Comment: Not more information with laravel-debugbar ?

Comment: CSRF token mismatch.
D:\Xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php#83
Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException
            });
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException('CSRF token mismatch.');
    }


-- From Debugebar

Comment: Remove `enctype="text/plain"` from your form

Comment: Tried that already. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used 'web' middleware to the form endpoint route. This middleware is responsible for web sessions

Comment: web middleware is there.